# Puzzled by descendant css with word line in it

Tags: css, selector

I’m trying to understand the below CSS.

I get that this is one form of a descendant selector. So it was easy for me to understand that

```css
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

means: select anchor tags if they’re inside list items.

But what does the below CSS do? `.axis` is a class name, but what is `line`?

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: grey;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from MDN

[**Line**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line)

> The line element is an SVG basic shape, used to create a line connecting two points.

[**Path**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path)

> The path element is the generic element to define a shape. All the basic shapes can be created with a path element.

Comment: Thank you for all. This is most specific and direct help for my question. But I appreciate everyone help. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is CSS meant for SVG which has different set of tags.
SVG are used to draw vector graphics and use XML-like format like the one used by HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`path` and `line` probably refers to SVG markup. Since it's also using `fill` and `stroke`.